# Нужна помощь с плагином Contact Form 7

Tags: php, wordpress

Описываю сценарий:
При открытии модального окна появляется попап-форма CF7. При нажатии на кнопку "Отправить" с незаполненными полями, не выводит текст ошибки и появляется просто рамка (см. скриншот), все поля уведомлений заполнены нужным текстом.

[image: Вот скриншот]

Answer (score 0):

Предполагаю, что текст внутри просто скрыт. Откройте консоль разработчика и проверьте теги на предмет display:none или отправьте сам сайт